# javascript array or objects how to add multi items with same key

Tags: javascript, object

javascript array how to add multiples values for same key

I want to referre to root menu with it's sub menu

like the following

menu and sub menu

```
root menu 0 ids -> 1,2,3
sub menu 1 ids -> 5,7
sub menu 2 ids -> 9

arr[0]=[1,2,3];
arr[1]=[5,7];
arr[2]=[9];
```

I try

```
arr[0].push(1);
arr[0].push(2);
```

arr[0] store last value only 2

if array not do that can do same exmple with array of objects

Comment: Is `arr[0]` an array? If it is your code will push both 1 and 2 into it.

Comment: You could make it a 2D array. E.g. `arr[0] = [];` `arr[0].push(1); arr[0].push(2)`. Then `console.log(arr[0]);` ---> `[1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you are expecting. Try the code blow.

#### Example 1

```js
let arr = [];
let rootMenu = [1,2,3];
let subMenu_1 = [5,7];
let subMenu_2 = [9];

arr.push(rootMenu);
arr.push(subMenu_1);
arr.push(subMenu_2);

console.log(arr);
```

#### Example 2

```js
let arr = Array.from({length:3}, () => []);
console.log(arr);
// Output: [[], [], []]

arr[0].push(1);
arr[0].push(2);
arr[0].push(3);
arr[1].push(5);
arr[1].push(7);
arr[2].push(9)

console.log(arr);
```

#### Example 3

```js
let arr = [];

arr[0] = [];
arr[0].push(1);
arr[0].push(2);
arr[0].push(3);

arr[1] = [];
arr[1].push(5);
arr[1].push(7);

arr[2] = [];
arr[2].push(9)

console.log(arr);
```